# Parse.com cannot access pointer to PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, pointers, parse-platform

I have the object GroupRequest and Group on Parse.com.  Each GroupRequest has a pointer to a Group object called "group".  I have queried to obtain an array of GroupRequests, and now I am trying to display the "name" string property of each Group in the GroupRequests in that array on a table view.

However, I am running into trouble when I try to access [@"name"].  The program crashes and says:

"'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Key "name" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.'"

How can I access the group names properly? Below is the code I'm using to try to access the [@"name"] property:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"notificationCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

self.pendingRequestBeingDisplayed = [self.pendingRequests objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

self.tempGroup = self.pendingRequestBeingDisplayed[@"group"];

cell.textLabel.text = self.tempGroup[@"name"];


return cell;
```

}

self.pendingRequests is the array of GroupRequest Objects.

Answer (score 1):

you need to get pointer fields by writing

> [query includeKey:@"group"];

Comment: wait so if I query to get the grouprequests, would I then have to query again to get the users in "to" and then query again to get the "group" PFObject I want?

Comment: what i'm saying is...is there anyway to access PFObjects using the pointer? I don't want to have to use a query every time.

Comment: No, you don't have to query every time for nested objects if you include the sub-object key.

Comment: If you have only the pointer then you always have to query to get the corresponding object. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a query, by default you get the pointer fields as pointers, not as `PFObjects`. If you want to get the pointer fields as `PFObjects`, you have to call

```
[query includeKey: @"the_name_of_the_pointer_column"];
```

before you execute the query.

Comment: wait so if I query to get the grouprequests, would I then have to query again to get the users in "to" and then query again to get the "group" PFObject I want?

Comment: No, if you use includeKey, then it is just one query.